# primary key auto increments

Tags: mysql

I have a database with two tables that currently has 3 columns each.

**Table_A**: `id`, `uid`, `url`

**Table_B**: `id`, `uid`, `url`

The `id` is the primary key that auto increments by `1` on each new row inserted.

The question I have is do I need a primary key still. I will never query the db for `id`.
The `uid` column is simply to separate per user so it's not unique per row.
*`Table_A`* and *`Table_B`* will be compared by `uid` often.
I have `uid`, `url` indexed and I expect the table to grow possible in the billions and I don't want to waste space on a `id`.

Comment: ALL tables in a RDBMS require a Primary Key. However it does not need to be a dedicated, ('surrogate'), auto-incrementing id. It can instead be a 'natural' key formed on one or more columns in the table, or (depending on the database engine) a combination of both!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use InnoDB, and don't declare a primary key column, InnoDB will create one for you, using a 6-byte integer.  So the only thing you're gaining by dropping the id column is possibly trading an 8-byte BIGINT for the 6-byte implicit PK column.

The reason is that InnoDB tables are stored as a B-tree, a clustered index based on the primary key.  Every table must have a column it uses to organize this B-tree, even if it's an implicitly created column.

You can also declare a table with a compound primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_A (
  uid INT NOT NULL,
  url VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (uid, url)
);
```

In this case, the requirement for a primary key is satisfied, and InnoDB creates no implicit column.

---

Re your comments:

I try not to use MyISAM.  MyISAM is more susceptible to data corruption than InnoDB, and usually InnoDB performs better because it caches both data and indexes.  It's true there are some cases where MyISAM can use less disk space, but disk space is cheap and I'd much rather get the benefits of InnoDB.

Regarding indexes, if you have `PRIMARY KEY(uid, url)` then you automatically have a compound index over those two columns.  No need to create an extra index on uid.

But if you have queries that search for url alone, without looking for a specific uid, then you need a separate index on url.

I talk more about index design in my presentation:  [How to Design Indexes, Really](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really)

Comment: Thank you +1 for the example. I'm debating to use innodb or myisam. There will be a lot of comparing of the data by uid. I do notice if I use myisam the table size drops a 3rd then innodb.

Comment: @Madbreaks should I still add indexs to uid and url?

Comment: Thank you and the only query I have that is separate from uid-url is table_b where it `delete from table_b WHERE uid ='$uid' but that table will only have temporary rows until it's compared.

Answer (score 1):

Technically no, although it's good practice and you never know what your future requirements will be.  If you end up needing a unique `id` column and don't have one, it could be a major headache.  The amount of overhead "wasted" on the `id` column is absolutely worth it in my opinion.

In addition, depending on the relationship between `Table_A` and `Table_b`, you may end up having an intermediary table to define the relationship between them (e.g. `one-to-nany`, `many-to-many`).  For highly efficient queries in such scenarios, the unique `id` column becomes a necessity.

Comment: Well the id is set `255` chars so a billion + rows will eat up some space. I understand innodb creates one if you don't have one.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the `id` columns, but it seems to me that your "primary" key is `uid-url`

Comment: I will be using queries like this `WHERE uid = '$uid' AND url = '$url'` you are correct there will never be two rows the same by uid-url how would I make that a primary key?

Comment: @AbbyE in the create statement: `PRIMARY KEY (uid, url)`